# Qt : QXmlQuery and XPaths

Tags: c++, qt, xpath

I'm here to ask you some help with *QXmlQuery* and *Xpath*.
I'm trying to use this combination to extract some data from several HTML documents.
These documents are downloaded and then cleaned with the [*HTML Tidy Library*](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).

The problem is when I try my XPath. Here is an example code :

```
[...]
    <ul class="bullet" id="idTab2">
        <li><span>Hauteur :</span> 1127 mm</li>
        <li><span>Largeur :</span> 640 mm</li>
        <li><span>Profondeur :</span> 685 mm</li>
        <li><span>Poids :</span> 159.6 kg</li>
[...]
```

The clean code is stored in a QString "code" :

```cpp
QStringList fields, values;
QXmlQuery query;

query.setFocus(code);
query.setQuery("//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/*/*/string()");
query.evaluateTo(&fields);
```

My goal is to get all the fields (Hauteur, Largeur, Profondeur, Poids, etc.) and their value (1127 mm, 640 mm, 685 mm, 159.6 kg, etc.).

**Question 1**

As you can see, I use this XPath `//*[@id="idTab2"]/*/*/string()` to recover the fields because this : `//ul[@id="idTab2"]/li/span/string()` doesn't work. When I try to specify a tag name, it gives me nothing. It only works with `*`. Why ? I've checked the code returned by the tidy function and the XPath is not altered. So, I don't see any prolem. Is this normal ? Or maybe there is something I don't know...

**Question 2**

In the previous XHTML code, the li tags wrap a span tag and some text. I don't know how to get only the text and not the content of the span tag. I tried :

`//*[@id="idTab2"]/*/string()` gives : `Hauteur : 1127 mm Largeur : 640 mm Profondeur : 685 mm`

`//*[@id="idTab2"]/*[2]/string()` gives : `Nothing`

So, if I'm not wrong, the text in the li tag is not considered as a child node but it should be. See the accepted answer : [Select just text directly in node, not in child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483972/select-just-text-directly-in-node-not-in-child-nodes).

Thanks for reading, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1):

To get the elements (not the text representation) inside the different `<li>`s, you can test the text content:

```
//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Hauteur")]
```

Same thing of other items:

```
//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Largeur")]
//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Profondeur")]
//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Poids")]
```

To get the string representation of these `<li>`, you can use `string()` around the whole expression, like this:

```
string(//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Poids")])
```

which gives "Poids : 159.6 kg"

To extract only the text node in the `<li>`, without the `<span>`, you can use these expressions, which select the text nodes which are direct children of `<li>` (`<span>` is not a text node), and removes the leading and trailing whitespace characters (`normalize-space()`)

```
normalize-space(//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Hauteur")]/text())
normalize-space(//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Largeur")]/text())
normalize-space(//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Profondeur")]/text())
normalize-space(//*[@id=\"idTab2\"]/li[starts-with(span, "Poids")]/text())
```

The last on gives "159.6 kg"

Comment: Hello @paul t., thank you for the answer but it doesn't seem to work too. I guess the problem comes from Qt, which doesn't seem to evaluate the XPath expressions as expected. I don't understand why... I'll search more about that.

Comment: OK. Fyi, I tested those using `lxml`